# Convert triple-triple to object-table in Sqlite JSON1

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite-json1

I have an Sqlite table `triples` that contains triple information in `{ id, rel, tgt }` format [1]. I would like to create a view that exposes this triple-format data to "object format", which is more easily consumed by applications reading from this database. In theory sqlite's JSON1 extension would allow me to construct such objects, but I'm struggling.

My current query

```sql
select distinct json_object(
  'id', id,
  rel, json_group_array(distinct tgt)
) as entity from content
group by src, rel, tgt
order by src, rel, tgt
```

does not work correctly. It produces objects like

```
{ id: 'a', 'is': ['b'] }
{ id: 'a', 'is': ['c'] }
```

Rather than

```
{ id: 'a', 'is': ['b', 'c'] }
```

It also produces duplicate keys like

```
{ id: 'a', id: ['a'] }
```

### *Edit*

This is closer, but does not handle IDs correctly. It constructs an array, not a string

```
create view if not exists entity as
  select distinct json_group_object(
    rel, json_array(distinct tgt)
  ) as entity from content
  group by src
```

I think `iif` might help

### Question;

Can you help me adjust my query to produce correct output (see below)? Please comment if anything needs disambiguation or clarification

### Desired Output

Input:

**Triple Format**:

```
id   | rel   | tgt
-----------------------
Bob   | is     | Bob
Bob   | is     | Person
Bob   | age    | 20
Bob   | likes  | cake
Bob   | likes  | chocolate
Alice | id     | Alice
Alice | is     | Person
Alice | hates  | chocolate
```

Output:

**Object Format** [2]:

```
{
  id:    Bob,
  is:    [ Person ],
  age:   [ 20 ],
  likes: [ cake, chocolate ]
}

{
  id:    Alice,
  is:    [ Person ],
  hates: [ chocolate ]
}
```

### Details

[1] This dataset has unpredictable structure; I can assume no prior knowledge of what 'rel' keys exist beyond `id`. A triple `<src> id <src>` will exist for every `src` parameter.

[2] The objects should have the following format. `id` must not be overwritten.

```
{ 
  id: <id>
  <distinct rel>: [ 
    < tgt >
  ]
}
```

### Relevant Information

- https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html

Comment: Don't group on `tgt`?

Comment: Thanks for commenting! I tried that initially but it doesn't appear to improve things; I can see both defects present after making this change

Comment: Do you actually have in the column `rel` values `likes` and `like`, `is` and `id`?

Comment: I do. I understand this isn't an especially relational way to store data, but sqlite is my preferred embedded database and I believe it will work effectively for this problem (triple storage & search)

Comment: How do you expect `likes` and `like` to be grouped in the same group?

Comment: Sorry; that _was_ a typo, though `is` and `id` are different relations

Comment: If you tried grouping by `src, rel` (not `tgt`), but it `doesn't appear to improve things`, please include the code you actually tried and the results it gave.

Comment: I updated with a query that works as expected, apart from the `id` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE content (
  id    VARCHAR(32),
  rel   VARCHAR(32),
  tgt   VARCHAR(32)
);
INSERT INTO
  content
VALUES
  ('Bob'  , 'id'   , 'Bob'),
  ('Bob'  , 'is'   , 'Person'),
  ('Bob'  , 'age'  , '20'),
  ('Bob'  , 'likes', 'cake'),
  ('Bob'  , 'likes', 'chocolate'),
  ('Alice', 'id'   , 'Alice'),
  ('Alice', 'is'   , 'Person'),
  ('Alice', 'hates', 'chocolate')
```

```
WITH
  id_rel AS
(
  SELECT
    id,
    rel,
    JSON_GROUP_ARRAY(tgt)  AS tgt
  FROM
    content
  GROUP BY
    id,
    rel
)
SELECT
  JSON_GROUP_OBJECT(
    rel,
    CASE WHEN rel='id'
         THEN JSON(tgt)->0
         ELSE JSON(tgt)
    END
  )
    AS entity
FROM
  id_rel
GROUP BY
  id
ORDER BY
  id
```

| entity |
| --- |
| {"hates":["chocolate"],"id":"Alice","is":["Person"]} |
| {"age":["20"],"id":"Bob","is":["Person"],"likes":["cake","chocolate"]} |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7Kb2oRBK)

You ***must*** aggregate in two steps, as your edited code ***doesn't*** combine `cake` and `chocolate` in to a single array of two elements...

- https://dbfiddle.uk/9ptyuhuj